# Find area of Ellipse whose points are GPS coordinates

Tags: python, r, gps, ellipse

I have set of get gps coordinates lets say n=100.I am trying to fit least area ellipse that encloses all the gps coordinates. I found a function [ellipsoidhull](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cluster/versions/2.0.8/topics/ellipsoidhull) in R which does this. Using this function along with [predict](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cluster/versions/2.0.8/topics/predict.ellipsoid) fucntion,i got the coordinates of the points on ellipse and the center of the ellipse which encloses all the data points i have. 
This function just treats the points as cartesian coordinates so i cannot use this function for futher calculate the  area of ellipse as it involves gps coordinates making the distances the different.

I dont know how to use these coordinates and combine them with gps distances to obtain the exact area of ellipse.

Assuming you have (m=400)gps ellipse coordinates and center of ellipse, how would you calculate the area, length of semi-major and minor-axis. Any mathematical solution or code in R or python is appreciated.

Comment: If you have the points on the edge of the ellipse (from `predict`) you could calculate the area using `geosphere::areaPolygon`

Comment: @AndrewGustar thanks that helps. I also need length of semi major and minor access.

Comment: I guess there must be a way of identifying the ends of the semi-axes from the output of `ellipsoidhull`, which you can then plug in to `geosphere::distGeo`